# Truncated expectation of sum of independent random variables

Tags: random-variable, conditional-expectation, truncated-distributions

Take three random variables $X$, $Y$, $Z$  s.t.  $E[X]>0$, $E[Y|X]=0$, $Z = X+Y$.

What can I say about $E[x| x> k]$ vs. $E[z| z>k]$ where $k>0$? Intuitively, the latter should be bigger but I have failed to (dis)prove it. Any hint/reference?

Comment: Let $(X,Y)\in\{(1,-1/4),(1,1),(2,0),(10,0)\}$ with probabilities $1/10,4/10,1/4,1/4$ respectively.  Verify this satisfies all your conditions, then consider $k=1.$

Comment: Thanks a lot @whuber! Probabilities should be $4/10$, $1/10$, $1/4$, $1/4$ but all the rest checks out. I guess the take away is that noise can add mass in the center but take it away from tails. I wonder about the sufficient conditions so that noise adds mass in the right tail as well, but I will need to think about this more carefully

Comment: Sorry about transposing the probabilities--I'm glad you understood my intention.